# Epson NX430 printing blue streaks

Tags: windows-10, printer

I am using Windows 10 running on a DELL Optiplex 780.

My Epson NX420 printer prints pale blue streaks along with text. Actually it looks like a an over-sized highlight. Ink was not low, but I replaced all four cartridges and the problem persists.

I ran through the head cleaning and other utilities. They did not fix the problem.

Comment: Sounds like the printer head should be clearned.  Follow Epson's cleaning instructions and/or replace it.

Comment: Printheads can build up a wad of semi-dried ink that doesn't block the nozzles, but smears on the paper.  If the printhead is a user-replaceable part, it is probably held in place with a lever and can be removed after removing the ink cartridges, and you can clean it out of the printer.  If it isn't easily removable, unplug the printer so you can slide the printhead to an accessible area.  Then work a lint-free cloth under it, wetted with water or isopropyl alcohol, and use it to wipe off the crud.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This printer is about three years old. Maybe it's time to buy a new one. I guess I've got my money's worth out of it.